# Read log file entries based on logged in user name

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, java-8, log4j2

I have a log file like below

```
    2023-06-13 09:48:07,060 [127.0.0.1 APP-NAME#USER_A] org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:94) Thread=default task-10

    - DEBUG -     
    select 
       this_.column1 as column1_,
       ....
    from
       table this_
    where
       this_.id=? 
    2023-06-13 09:48:07,131 [127.0.0.1 APP-NAME#USER_A] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) Thread=default task-10
    - TRACE - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [k24gEQ7O3PjWBnPSDcwcwz3baOUN8Vhmh0BqDcIg]
    2023-06-13 09:48:07,132 [127.0.0.1 APP-NAME#USER_A] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) Thread=default task-10
    - TRACE - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [CORE-ADMIN]
    2023-06-13 12:06:21,588 [127.0.0.1 APP-NAME#USER_B] org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:94) Thread=default task-40

    - DEBUG - 
select
    this_.id as id_,
from
    table this_
where
    this_.id=? 
    2023-06-13 09:48:07,131 [127.0.0.1 APP-NAME#USER_B] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) Thread=default task-10
    - TRACE - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [k24gEQ7O3PjWBnPSDcwcwz3baOUN8Vhmh0BqDcIg]
    2023-06-13 09:48:07,132 [127.0.0.1 APP-NAME#USER_B] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) Thread=default task-10
    - TRACE - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [CORE-ADMIN]
```

I need to get the query generated by USER_B alone with all binded parameters.

Can anyone help me with this.

I am using java 8, log4j2, spring boot, hibernate.

Comment: Do you **need** to parse the logfiles or can you modify the configuration to separate log statements by user? What is your current configuration?

Comment: use grep to filter only USER_B queries. 
Ex: <loggilename> | grep APP-NAME#USER_B